# Probability Fair Coins toss $W_{t+1}=1+W_{t}$ or $W_{t+1}= 1/W_{t}$

Tags: probability

A guy has initial wealth of $W_{0} = 1000$. For each fair coin toss, his wealth change as: $W_{t+1}=1+W_{t}$ for heads or $W_{t+1} = 1/W_{t}$ for tails . Find the approximate value of $E[W_{5}]$.

I used Monte Carlo to get the answer is about $251$. I would like to know if there is any method to approximate the value without using simulations..

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are 32 outcomes, so you can calculate each exactly.
You only retain a fortune if tails come in pairs.  When your fortune is around 1/1000, a head will wipe you out.  You need another tail immediately.
There are eight of the 32 outcomes where that happens: HHHHH,HHHTT,HHTTH,HTTHH,TTHHH,HTTTT,TTHTT,TTTTH, which is why $E[W_5]$ is around a quarter of your initial fortune.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how about if I want E[W_10] instead? Then it is nearly impossible to calculate each outcome exactly

Comment: Can you show the number of outcomes where you retain your fortune is a Fibonacci number?

Comment: Thank you. Now I can spot that once you remind me..but I still don't know how to prove it mathematically..can you give me some hints please